# authentication with mercury-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, mercury-editor

How do you add authentication checks on the /editor/.* routes in [Mercury](http://jejacks0n.github.com/mercury/) via the `mercury-rails` gem?

I mean, I know you can:

- hide the link to the editor when not authenticated.
- refuse updates from the editor when not authenticated.

But I'd prefer the user be kicked out of the editor incase he/she has a bookmark to the editor and isn't logged in.

PS: Can someone create a `mercury-editor` tag for this? Otherwise searching for mercury-editor is neigh impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like now the mercury-rails installer will ask you if you want them to add some authentication code, and if you do it creates

lib/mercury/authentication.rb

```
module Mercury
  module Authentication

    def can_edit?
      true # check here to see if the user is logged in/has access
    end
  end
end
```

Where you can run your check code in there.  Maybe something like "if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin?"

Answer (score 7):

A before_filter method is probably what you would want to use.

You could just add your own controller than inherits from the MercuryController and point the routes to your controller:

In config/routes.rb:

```
...
match '/editor(/*requested_uri)' => "my_mercury#edit", :as => :mercury_editor
Mercury::Engine.routes
...
```

And app/controllers/my_mercury_controller.rb

```
class MyMercuryController < MercuryController
    before_filter :login_required
    def login_required
        ...
    end
end
```